# Deviceを使用したアプリで、Rspecを用いてテストする場合

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

初めて、Deviceを使用したアプリで、Rspecを用いてテストしようとしています。

はじめにコントローラーのテストファイルに、以下を追加して、正常なレスポンスが帰ってくるかのテストをしようとしています。

```
it "returns a 200 response" do
get :index
  expect(response).to have_http_status "200"
end
```

その結果、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
Devise::MissingWarden:
       Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
       Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
       If you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the `request.env['warden']` object for you.
```

修正する方法を調べ、spec_helper.rbに以下のコードを追加しましました。

```
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
```

しかし、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Devise
```

再び調査し、application.rbに

```
require 'devise'
```

を入れてみたのですが、エラーが変わらなく全てのページにおいてテストすることができません。

どうすれば解決できるでしょうか。

Comment: 過去の質問もそうですが、解決した場合は回答を承認してください。もし解決しなかったのであれば、補足するなり回答を受けた結果に対してなんらかのアクションをお願いいたします。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。承認機能があるということを認識しておりませんでした。今後は承認・アクションを行います

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require 'devise'`が抜けているのではないでしょうか？
`rails_helper.rb`に以下のような記載をするをするのが一般的だと思います。

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
# note: require 'devise' after require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # For Devise > 4.1.1
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
  # Use the following instead if you are on Devise <= 4.1.1
  # config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

公式ページ
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-%28and-RSpec%29#controller-specs